# Database Foreign Key is Retaining value on new Record

Tags: ms-access

I have a Database for Invoicing. And a Form to bring all the tables together and create a invoice. My customers have individual pricing for the product. The sub-form pulls the customer pricing up by using a criteria on a Query based Drop-down List. My criteria is as follows:

```
[Forms]![Invoice]![Job_ID]
```

I also have a button. It has the following code:

```
Private Sub Invoice_Button_Click()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
End Sub
```

My problem is after clicking the button and going to a new record the sub-form Job_ID from the previous record carries over. The only way to fix it and get the right pricing is to go back to the record later and select the product again. It works fine when I open the invoice on a new record and only add 1 record, close and reopen it.

--New Info

To clarify there is a main form with a sub form. In the main form I have a combo box named Job_ID the subform has a product ID # that uses a select Query to limit the number of options based on the Job_ID as to avoid selecting the wrong price. However its retaining the Job_ID from the previous invoice.

Comment: DoCmd.Save is not needed nor does it do what you think - it doesn't save record, it is to save object design. Record should be saved when moving to next record. Why is there a `.` between Do and Cmd? That should not compile.

Comment: Possibly need to Requery the combobox. But why would Product auto populate? Is there some code we need to see?

Comment: Adding new info in. '.' Is in there on accident.